# To calculate the percentage of items for various item types using SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, cube, rollup

My table is as follows

```
ITEM_CREATION_DATE  ITEM_ID ITEM_TYPEID ITEM_FOLDER
2008-04-04 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  12  Y
2008-12-14 00:00:00.000 ITEM04  13  Y
2008-09-24 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  13  Y
2009-12-04 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  12  NULL
2009-04-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM02  13  NULL
2010-08-13 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  13  Y
2010-01-28 00:00:00.000 ITEM02  14  Y
2011-04-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM03  13  NULL
2011-10-19 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  12  NULL
2011-04-29 00:00:00.000 ITEM04  13  NULL
2011-02-19 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  13  NULL
2011-04-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM03  13  NULL
2012-02-29 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  14  Y
2012-12-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM03  14  Y
2012-07-19 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  14  Y
2012-06-29 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  12  Y
2012-04-29 00:00:00.000 ITEM03  NULL    Y
2012-04-19 00:00:00.000 ITEM03  NULL    Y
2013-04-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  13  Y
2013-09-14 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  13  Y
2013-05-24 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  12  Y
2013-01-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  12  Y
2013-11-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  14  Y
2013-09-21 00:00:00.000 ITEM01  12  Y
2013-07-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM02  14  Y
2013-08-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM02  NULL    Y
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ITEM02  NULL    Y
```

I need to get the percentage of items across various Item types. The challenge here is to accomplish the same in a single query.

I need the result as follows

```
Year     12     13      14  NULL
2008    33.33%      66.66%      0.00%   0.00%
2009    0.00%       0.00%       0.00%   0.00%
2010    0.00%       50%     50% 0.00%
2011    0.00%       0.00%       0.00%   0.00%
2012    16.66%      0.00%       50% 33.33%
2013    33.33%      22.22%      22.22%  22.22%
```

Th best way to tackle this query is Pivot, so I started in that direction. 
I am very new to these type of queries, so please I need the help from you experts.

I managed to get the query with the counts of the item for the various item types

```
select *  from 
(
SELECT  YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE) AS [Year], ITEM_ID, ITEM_TYPEID FROM [dbo].[ITEM_DETAIL] 
WHERE ITEM_FOLDER IS NOT NULL 
) AS Result pivot (count(ITEM_ID) for ITEM_TYPEID in ([12],[13],[14])) as MyTbl
```

OUTPUT
Year     12     13      14

```
2008    1       2       0
2010    0       1       1
2012    1       0       3
2013    3       2       2
```

But the problem here is I am missing the rest of the years (i.e 2009 and 2011) because they do not fall under the where clause (ITEM_FOLDER IS NOT NULL)
I need all the years in the table.

Also the NULL item type is not fetched in my query.

Please tell me if I have the correct approach to solve this. It can easily be done with multiple SQL inside a stored procedure. But that is not aa feasible solution in my case. I need to execute a single SQL query to get the desired output

```
Looks like if PIVOT is used I can get only Count or Percentage but not both.

Can I get the same thing like this taken into account if Year is NULL and ITEM_TYPE is NULL

2008    12  1   33.33%
2008    13  2   66.66%
2009    12  1   50.00%
2009    13  1   50.00%
2010    13  1   50.00%
2010    14  1   50.00%
2011    12  1   20.00%
2011    13  4   80.00%
2012    NULL    2   33.33%
2012    12  1   16.66%
2012    14  3   50.00%
2013    NULL    2   22.22%
2013    12  3   33.33%
2013    13  2   22.22%
2013    14  2   22.22%



The output is not right.

For the years where the ITEM_FOLDER is null , the counts must be 0 for all the item types
And for a year if there are only records for one item type , need to display the counts as 0 for the rest of all item types

Like this one below

YEAR    ITEM_TYPE   COUNT   PERCENTAGE
2008    12      1   33.33
2008    13      2   66.67
2008    14      0   0.00
2009    12      0   0.00
2009    13      0   0.00
2009    14      0   0.00
2010    12      0   0.00
2010    13      1   50.00
2010    14      1   50.00
2011    12      0   0.00
2011    13      0   0.00
2011    14      0   0.00
2012    NULL    2   33.33
2012    12      1   16.67
2012    13      0   0.00
2012    14      3   50.00
2013    NULL    2   22.22
2013    12      3   33.33
2013    13      2   22.22
2013    14      2   22.22
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT [Year],[12],[13],[14],[0] AS [NULL]  FROM 
(
    SELECT  YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE) AS [Year]
    , CASE WHEN ITEM_FOLDER IS NOT NULL THEN ITEM_ID ELSE NULL END AS [ITEM_ID]
    , ISNULL(ITEM_TYPEID,0) AS ITEM_TYPEID FROM ITEM_DETAIL
) AS Result 
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT(ITEM_ID) for ITEM_TYPEID in ([12],[13],[14],[0])
) as MyTbl
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/123627)

**EDIT**

For percentages check below

```
SELECT [Year]
    ,Convert(DECIMAL(8,2), [12]*100/Convert(DECIMAL(8,2),Total)) AS [12]
    ,Convert(DECIMAL(8,2), [13]*100/Convert(DECIMAL(8,2),Total)) AS [13]
    ,Convert(DECIMAL(8,2), [14]*100/Convert(DECIMAL(8,2),Total)) AS [14]
    ,Convert(DECIMAL(8,2), [NULL]*100/Convert(DECIMAL(8,2),Total)) AS [NULL] 
FROM
(
    SELECT [Year],[12],[13],[14],[0] AS [NULL],
    (SELECT COUNT(ITEM_ID) FROM #ITEM_DETAIL WHERE YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE) = MyTbl.[Year] GROUP BY YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE)) AS Total 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE) AS [Year]
        , CASE WHEN ITEM_FOLDER IS NOT NULL THEN ITEM_ID ELSE NULL END AS [ITEM_ID]
        , ISNULL(ITEM_TYPEID,0) AS ITEM_TYPEID FROM ITEM_DETAIL
    ) AS Result 
    PIVOT 
    (
        COUNT(ITEM_ID) for ITEM_TYPEID in ([12],[13],[14],[0])
    ) as MyTbl
) T
```

[**PERCENTAGE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/123691)

**EDIT 2**

```
SELECT 
    [YEAR]
    ,ITEM_TYPEID
    ,CNT
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),CNT*100/CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),TOTAL)) AS PERCENTAGE 
FROM
(
    SELECT [YEAR],ITEM_TYPEID,SUM(CNT) AS CNT
    ,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #ITEM_DETAIL T1 WHERE YEAR(T1.ITEM_CREATION_DATE)=T.[YEAR]
         GROUP BY YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE)) AS [TOTAL]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE) AS [YEAR]
         , ISNULL(ITEM_TYPEID,'NULL') AS ITEM_TYPEID 
         , 1 AS CNT
        FROM #ITEM_DETAIL  
    ) T
    GROUP BY [YEAR],ITEM_TYPEID
) T1
ORDER BY [YEAR]
```

[**PERCENTAGE DEMO 2**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/123848)

```
SELECT [Year],C.itemtype,C.cnt,C.percentage FROM
(
    SELECT [Year],[12]
        ,Convert(DECIMAL(8,2), [12]*100/Convert(DECIMAL(8,2),Total)) AS [12p],[13]
        ,Convert(DECIMAL(8,2), [13]*100/Convert(DECIMAL(8,2),Total)) AS [13p],[14]
        ,Convert(DECIMAL(8,2), [14]*100/Convert(DECIMAL(8,2),Total)) AS [14p],[NULLv] 
        ,Convert(DECIMAL(8,2), [NULLv]*100/Convert(DECIMAL(8,2),Total)) AS [NULLp] 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [Year],[12],[13],[14],[0] AS [NULLv],
        (SELECT COUNT(ITEM_ID) FROM #ITEM_DETAIL WHERE YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE) = MyTbl.[Year] GROUP BY YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE)) AS Total 
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT  YEAR(ITEM_CREATION_DATE) AS [Year]
            , CASE WHEN ITEM_FOLDER IS NOT NULL THEN ITEM_ID ELSE NULL END AS [ITEM_ID]
            , ISNULL(ITEM_TYPEID,0) AS ITEM_TYPEID FROM #ITEM_DETAIL
        ) AS Result 
        PIVOT 
        (
            COUNT(ITEM_ID) for ITEM_TYPEID in ([12],[13],[14],[0])
        ) as MyTbl
    ) T
) P
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES
    ('12',[12],[12p]),
    ('13',[13],[13p]),
    ('14',[14],[14p]),
    ('NULL',NULLv,[NULLp])
) C(itemtype,cnt,percentage)
WHERE C.itemtype <> 'NULL' OR C.cnt > 0
```

[**PERCENTAGE DEMO 3**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/124106)

Comment: I need the count and percentage in one query.  Thanks much.

Comment: <pre>Looks like if PIVOT is used I can get only Count or Percentage but not both.

Can I get the same thing like this taken into account if Year is NULL and ITEM_TYPE is NULL

2008 12 1 33.33%
2008 13 2 66.66%
2009 12 1 50.00%
2009 13 1 50.00%
2010 13 1 50.00%
2010 14 1 50.00%
2011 12 1 20.00%
2011 13 4 80.00%
2012 NULL 2 33.33%
2012 12 1 16.66%
2012 14 3 50.00%
2013 NULL 2 22.22%
2013 12 3 33.33%
2013 13 2 22.22%
2013 14 2 22.22%</pre>

Comment: <pre>Looks like if PIVOT is used I can get only Count or Percentage but not both.

Can I get the same thing like this taken into account if Year is NULL and ITEM_TYPE is NULL

2008 12 1 33.33%
2008 13 2 66.66%
2009 12 1 50.00%
2009 13 1 50.00%
2010 13 1 50.00%
2010 14 1 50.00%
2011 12 1 20.00%
2011 13 4 80.00%
2012 NULL 2 33.33%
2012 12 1 16.66%
2012 14 3 50.00%
2013 NULL 2 22.22%
2013 12 3 33.33%
2013 13 2 22.22%
2013 14 2 22.22%</pre>

Comment: The query does not give the desired output. Please check above.